# a simple question: whence the $\pi$ symbols in the solution of a trig equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

There's a step-by-step discussion of an example irrational trig equation in my textbook.

$$\sqrt{3\sin(2x)}=\sqrt{-5\cos(x)\cot(x)}$$

One of the solutions is 
$$\cos(x)=-\frac23$$

The solution to this is divided into two sequences as follows, in order to make sure the final solution complies with the condition that $\sin(2x)\ge0$

[image]

I don't recall why we can add those $\pi$ symbols there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Notice, we know that $$\cos(\pi-\theta)=-\cos \theta\tag 1$$
Let, $$\cos \theta=x\iff \theta =\cos^{-1}(x)$$ 
Where, $\color{blue}{-1\leq x\leq 1}$

Then substituting the value of $\theta$ in (1), we get $$\cos (\pi-\cos^{-1}(x))=-\cos(\cos^{-1}(x))$$

$$\cos (\pi-\cos^{-1}(x))=-x$$
 $$\pi-\cos^{-1}(x)=\cos^{-1}(-x)$$
$$\cos^{-1}(-x)=\pi-\cos^{-1}(x)$$

Hence, we have $$\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)=\color{red}{\pi}-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your observation